# HTML button to image

Tags: button

I have this code `<input type="submit" value="Register" />` 
How do I insert

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/m9KT9CQ.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/T9hpI23'" 
onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/m9KT9CQ.png'"/>
```

onto this button? Thanks!

Comment: Input type image is also available for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link

http://screwdesk.com/how-to-create-html-rollover-image-button-using-css/

basically this css

```
a.btn {
display: block;
width: 294px;
height: 87px;
cusror: pointer;
background-image: url(rollover-image-button-1.png);
text-indent: -9999em;
}
a.btn:hover {
background-image: url(rollover-image-button-2.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```html
<button type="submit">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m9KT9CQ.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/T9hpI23'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/m9KT9CQ.png'"/>
</button>
```